# How to copy the last (n)rows of a google sheet to a new sheet

Tags: function, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps

I am new to Google Apps and Google sheets and would appreciate a little help. I have a google sheet with some data in a table that is simply a date column and then a few columns of data collected from that date with a new row for each days data. I wish to copy the last 7 days, 30 days,  60 days etc to a new sheets. Essentially copy the last (x)Rows of a table to a new sheet where I can vary (x).

Is there a simply function that I can use on a new sheet to get the desired (x) rows from the table.
Or do I have to use a script. If so how do I proceed.

Any replies would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: You can search for similar questions, like this one:  [StackOverflow Filter by Date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15614697/can-i-filter-google-sheets-results-by-date-and-time-relevent-to-current-time)

Comment: Also, this:  [SO - Filter by date column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13439346/filter-rows-by-date-a-column-and-write-sum-c-column-to-field-in-another-shee)  If you put something together, and provide a link to a sheet with some dummy data in it, someone will be able to help.

Comment: As an example I would like to copy the last 7 days data from columns A and B on sheet 1 automaticall to sheet 2 and the last 30 days to sheet 3 on the followin document: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eDiuF28EZPkALEfcCF3bAm6NGvnNtGVq4BCdupy8zEA/pubhtml

Comment: You can run a script from a custom menu.  A custom menu can be added to the spreadsheet when the spreadsheet opens.  Would you prefer that over the spreadsheet formulas?

Answer (score 1):

I use the same technique in an activities schedule I built for the school I work for.  In my version I created I created a sheet for today and the next 7 days.   https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AnQ7SpwUoM8odDRKZWE2eVh4QTNzOWsyQmlkb3JvRVE&usp=sharing#gid=10

Below is the filter function I used for the next 7 days.

```
=filter('All Events'!A:H,('All Events'!A1:A1654=DATEVALUE(now()))+('All Events'!A1:A1654=DATEVALUE(now()+1))+('All Events'!A1:A1654=DATEVALUE(now()+2))+('All Events'!A1:A1654=DATEVALUE(now()+3))+('All Events'!A1:A1654=DATEVALUE(now()+4))+('All Events'!A1:A1654=DATEVALUE(now()+5))+('All Events'!A1:A1654=DATEVALUE(now()+6))+('All Events'!A1:A1654=DATEVALUE(now()+7)))
```

Answer (score 1):

To add a menu, and run code I've created the following code and explanation:

### Add a Function the runs when the spreadsheet opens:

Choose **TOOLS**, **SCRIPT EDITOR** and the code editor will open.  Paste in this `onOpen()` function.

```
function onOpen() {

  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
      .createMenu('Custom Menu')
      .addItem('Display User Dialog', 'displayUserDialog')
      .addToUi();
};
```

That code will run when you open the spreadsheet.  You will see a new Menu Item.
That code is set up to trigger some more code when you choose '**Display User Dialog**' from the Custom Menu.  You need to add more code.  Add this function:

```
function displayUserDialog() {

  //Logger.log('displayUserDialog ran: ');

  var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Dialog Copy Choices')
    .evaluate()
    .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.NATIVE)
    .setWidth(500)
    .setHeight(300);

  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
    .showModalDialog(html, 'My custom dialog');
};
```

The above two functions go into a `gs` script file.  I think a new script file is usually automatically created name:  **Code.gs**

Create a new HTML file:
From the FILE menu, choose NEW - HTML

### HTML File named "Dialog Copy Choices"

```
<div id="outer" style="padding:1;"/>

<div>
    <br>Sheet To Copy To:<br>
    <select id="idSheetNames">
      <?!= getSheetNames(); ?>
    </select>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div>Copy To:</div>
    <input id="idToCol" type='text' placeholder='Column To Copy to:'>
    <br>
    <input id="idToRow" type='text' placeholder='Row To Copy to:'>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div>Copy From:</div>
    <input id="idFromStart" type='text' placeholder='A1'>
    <br>
    <input id="idFromEnd" type='text' placeholder='D20:'>
    <br>
    <br> 
    <input type="button" value="Copy Cells" id="idCopyBtn" onclick="myFunction()">
</div>

<script>

function myFunction() {
  var sheetToGetData = document.getElementById("idSheetNames").value;
  var copyToRow = document.getElementById("idToRow").value;
  var copyToCol = document.getElementById("idToCol").value;

  var copyFromStart = document.getElementById("idFromStart").value;
  var copyFromEnd = document.getElementById("idFromEnd").value;

  //console.log("values of variables: " + sheetToGetData + " : " + copyToCol + " : " + copyToRow + " : " +  copyFromStart + " : " +  copyFromEnd);

  google.script.run.gsCopyData(sheetToGetData, copyToCol, copyToRow, copyFromStart, copyFromEnd);
  google.script.host.close();
};
</script>
```

Refresh the spreadsheet after adding all that code, and a new custom menu should appear.  Use the custom menu to display the dialog.

The custom dialog displays all the sheets in your spreadsheet in a drop down field.  The drop down allows you to choose what sheet to copy the data to:

### gs Code to Get Sheet Names

```
function getSheetNames() {
  var allSheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();

  var howManySheets = allSheets.length;
  var sheetNames = [];
  var htmlSelectOptions = "";
  var thisName = "";

  for (var i = 0;i < howManySheets; i++) {
    thisName = allSheets[i].getName();
    htmlSelectOptions += '<option value="' + thisName + '">' + thisName + '</option>';
  };

  return htmlSelectOptions;
};
```

### gs Code to Copy Data

```
function gsCopyData(sheetToGetData, copyToCol, copyToRow, copyFromStart, copyFromEnd) {
  //Logger.log(sheetToGetData + " : " + copyToCol + " : " + copyToRow + " : " + copyFromStart + " : " + copyFromEnd);
  //Logger.log("gsCopyData ran");

  var alphaBet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

  var rowStartCopy = Number(copyFromStart.slice(1));
  var colStartCopy = copyFromStart.slice(0,1);
  colStartCopy = 1 + alphaBet.indexOf(colStartCopy.toLowerCase());

  var rowEndCopy = Number(copyFromEnd.slice(1));
  var colEndCopy = copyFromEnd.slice(0,1);
  colEndCopy = 1 + alphaBet.indexOf(colEndCopy.toLowerCase());

  var numRows = rowEndCopy - rowStartCopy + 1;
  var numColumns = colEndCopy - colStartCopy + 1;

  var rangeToCopy = sheet.getRange(rowStartCopy, colStartCopy, numRows, numColumns);

  copyToCol = alphaBet.indexOf(copyToCol.toLowerCase()) + 1;

  var destinationSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetToGetData);

  //Logger.log(destinationSheet + copyToCol + numColumns + copyToRow + numRows);

  rangeToCopy.copyValuesToRange(destinationSheet, copyToCol, numColumns, copyToRow, numRows);
};
```

Comment: Thanks Sandy @sandygood I am learning a lot from your answer. The following is a link to a spreadsheet I have created following your instructions: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uIfz-py3V1N5yEdn7klhYcKl2T84xlm6MjW30G28MwA/pubhtml

Comment: I added some more code at the end that actually does the copying.  The method that does all the work is:  `copyValuesToRange(destinationSheet, copyToCol, numColumns, copyToRow, numRows)`  That's the key line of code.  Everything else is just preparation to run that line of code.

Answer (score 0):

A starting point would be to look at the three FILTER functions.

- FILTER
- SORT
- UNIQUE

Here is the link to the list of Google Spreadsheet functions:

[Google Support - Spreadsheet Function List](https://support.google.com/docs/table/25273?hl=en)

I'm sure there is a way, using functions, to filter the data you want.  If you want something more automated, you'd need to program something.  That would be more work.

Either way, it's possible.